# Transition Between a screen to a widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Say I have a screen which consists of a container e.g.

### Test.dart

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

and i wrap the container with a gesture detector which runs the `showDialog()` function which contains another container:

```dart
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    body: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        height: 500,
                        width: 300,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 70,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        )
```

Now I want the first container from the screen to transition to the dialog's container, so i wrap it with the Hero widget:

```dart
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    body: Center(
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: 'container',
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          height: 500,
                          width: 300,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          },
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'container',
            child: Container(
              height: 70,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

But it doesnt seem to be transitioning b/w the screens, So i try to wrap it with the `Material()` widget:

```dart
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    body: Center(
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: 'container',
                        child: Material(
                          type: MaterialType.transparency,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            height: 500,
                            width: 300,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          },
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'container',
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.transparency,
              child: Container(
                height: 70,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

BUT it still does'nt tranition... is there an alternative way to achieve the transition or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: The underlying purpose of the `Hero` widget is to trick the user into thinking a component is migrating across screens by duplicating that widget onto the overlay layer, animating its scale and movement from the source widget to the destination, and then disappearing the overlay widget when it is resting on top of the destination. However, dialogs by their very nature already exist on the overlay layer, so it's unclear to me if and how the `Hero` widget would rectify this. Short of creating a "fake dialog" in a new screen, I don't know if this problem currently has a solution.

Comment: @Abion47 Dialogs are actually just normal pages and are shown on screen with `Navigator.push(context, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output:

[image]

a. Create a custom `PageRoute` transition. Comments are minimal because most of the properties are self-explanatory, or can be read about in the docs.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AlignedDialogRoute extends PageRoute<void> {
  AlignedDialogRoute({
    super.settings,
    this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.alignment = Alignment.center,
    required this.heroTag,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(fullscreenDialog: false);

  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final Alignment alignment;

  /// The tag used to match the Hero transition widgets.
  final String heroTag;

  /// The builder will create the widget that we want to show in the dialog.
  final Widget Function(
    BuildContext,
    Animation<double>,
    Animation<double>,
  ) builder;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: Align(
          alignment: alignment,
          child: Hero(
            tag: heroTag,
            child: builder(context, animation, secondaryAnimation),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  Color? get barrierColor => Colors.black54;

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => "Dialog dismissal barrier";

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 300);
}
```

b. Example usage:

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => _showDialog(context),
            child: Hero(
              tag: "my_hero_tag", // Add a Hero tag.
              child: Container(
                width: 96.0,
                height: 96.0,
                color: Colors.cyan,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      AlignedDialogRoute(
        alignment: const Alignment(.0, -.33), // Change as needed.
        heroTag: "my_hero_tag", // Make sure the hero tag matches.
        builder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
          // Use Material to get default theme, or provide your own.
          return Material(
            child: Container(
              width: 192.0,
              height: 192.0,
              color: Colors.cyan,
              child: const Text("Dialog"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note 1: I did not look into making this behavior work with the current widgets, so some combination of existing components might work.

Note 2: Look into the `flightShuttleBuilder` parameter of `Hero` widgets.

Comment: Most thankful for your reply, it worked! but I have ran into another minor problem, I have some components in the dialog file that I would like to fade in after the dialog is open, but they seem to appear behind the dialog when it is opening during the animation but when the animation finishes the components seem to just pop up, i would like to make it so they have a subtle fade in animation after the animation is finished

Comment: Wrap your widget in `FadeTransition(opacity: animation, ...);` inside the builder. If that's not the effect you want, then look into this: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations